# Help with understanding point from Nassim Taleb's book "Dynamic Hedging"

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

This is an excerpt from Nassim Taleb's book "Dynamic Hedging" (a book on option trading strategies) page vii

> Most examples in this book are presented as generic situations. The
>   volatility will be defined as 15.7% (to make one standard deviation
>   equal to 1% daily move).

**I'm trying to understand where the numbers 15.7% and 1% came from. How were they derived or estimated?**

---

Edit: Adding more context, here's a screen cap of the actual text:
[image]

Comment: Maybe the discussion under "Mathematical definition" on the wiki page will help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatility_(finance)

Comment: @gogurt Thanks... I think that discussion explains it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a 248 day year, use $\sigma \sqrt{\frac{1}{248}} =.01$ to normalize for a daily $\sigma$ of $1\%$. This gives $\sigma \approx .157$.

Comment: Thanks Nassim ;-) ... as @gogurt commented, the "Mathematical definition" here has a clear explanation: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatility_(finance) –

Comment: NNT, why 248 but 252 day year?

Comment: Update: NNT has edited!